# What is the best way to create a Json table using python?

Tags: python, json, datatable

I am pulling from a sql database and want to store that data as a json table. Currently i have the output as a csv to be able to visualize the data easily in excel. I understand everything minus how to format and work with json files.

Comment: What is a "json table"?

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjujYW3i4fjAhVLaM0KHdhiAmYQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=%2Furl%3Fsa%3Di%26source%3Dimages%26cd%3D%26ved%3D%26url%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fsocial.technet.microsoft.com%252Fwiki%252Fcontents%252Farticles%252F37292.sql-server-2016-bulk-import-json-file-data-to-table.aspx%26psig%3DAOvVaw3UvjsiGhKYjkrcqrhsvhrJ%26ust%3D1561635525728063&psig=AOvVaw3UvjsiGhKYjkrcqrhsvhrJ&ust=1561635525728063

Comment: Basically a html table but using json i guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting a CSV to a JSON.

```
import csv
import json

csvfile = open('file.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('file.json', 'w')

fieldnames = ("FirstName", "LastName", "IDNumber", "Message")
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames)
for row in reader:
    json.dump(row, jsonfile)
    jsonfile.write('\n')
```

OR

A more feasible solution

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('final_coupa.csv')
df['json'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.to_json(), axis=1)

df['json'].to_csv('final_json', index=False)
```

Hope this helps.